Upper and lower bounds on $\lfloor x \rfloor$?
Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on the reals. I want to place upper and lower bounds on integrals of the form
$$\int_1^x \lfloor t\rfloor  f(t) \, dt$$
An obvious approach is to find continuously differentiable functions $g,h$ that offer tight-as-possible upper and lower bounds on $\lfloor x \rfloor$. So I am looking for $g,h$ such that
$$g(x) \le \lfloor x \rfloor \le h(x)$$
with $h(x) - g(x)$ as small as possible.
It's quite easy to find loose-fitting functions. For example, the equation-pair defined by
$$\int 2 \sin ^2(\pi  x) \, dx = 2 \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sin (2 \pi  x)}{4 \pi }\right) \le \lfloor x \rfloor \le 2 \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sin (2 \pi  x)}{4 \pi }\right) - 1$$
bracket $\lfloor x \rfloor$ nicely:

However, in this case, $h(x) - g(x) = 1$, which is quite a wide spread. (I realise that the difference is necessarily $\ge 1$ for integer values of $x$, but the spread elsewhere would ideally be smaller.)
Is it possible to do better?

Sure, just use bump functions or convolution to approximate $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to within what precision you want away from a small neighborhood of $\mathbb Z$. What's your goal with such a function? What sort of bounds are you hoping for? There's not going to be much hope of ever calculating analytic formulas for sufficiently tight approximations, so you'll have to make a concession somewhere.

Hi @Brevan. I am looking to establish tight-as possible bunds on integrals involving the floor function, i.e., expressions of the form $\int_1^x \lfloor t\rfloor  f(t) , dt$.

I recommend reading about “Selberg's magic functions” in Chapter 1 of Montgomery's "Ten Lectures on the Interface …". They're design to do precisely this kind of thing. (I would apply that method to the periodic mean-$0$ function $\lfloor x\rfloor - (x - \frac12)$ and then add $x-\frac12$ to the answer manually.)
